# What is rc stands for

Tags: language-agnostic, coding-style

I saw a lot of times code where return status of function was set to ***rc *** variable (e.g. *int rc = foo();*). I though it some sort of convention and blindly used it all over my code.

Recently was asked by colleague what ***rc *** stands for and discovered that I indeed don't know the answer.

Thanks

Comment: You really should be using variable names that make sense to you and other programmers on the project. If neither you nor your colleague understand what the variable name means, then that's a sign.

Comment: I consider "rc" to be from the same family as "i", we all use in for loops. These short variable a better in cases scope of variable is small. You don't need to vaste additional mind CPU cycles to interpret name of variable.

Comment: At the risk of political incorrectness, I'd suggest that the most suitable expansion would be "retarded coder". Using a name that has some many possible meanings (e.g., row/column, return code, remote control, ...) without clarifying fits the description pretty well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably refers to

```
Return Code
```

Comment: Yes I use `rc` only for the variable/value which I end up returning using a `return rc;` statement.

Comment: A more general name is 'rv', for return value.

Comment: Personally, I've always used 'ret' for RETurn.

Answer (score 0):

rc stands for run code for instance when you want a code block or function to run on startup of the code snippet rc will automatically run the code you attach to it